# VS Code выдает ошибку компиляции кода на C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

VS Code выдает ошибку Unable to start debugging. Programm path 'c:Users\User\Dekstop\Новая папка\hello.exe' is missing or invalid [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытаюсь вывести обыкновенный хеллоу ворлд.

Вот launch.json [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот c_cpp_properties.json
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот tasks.json [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Свойства всех этих файлов я не менял за исключением c_cpp_properties.json где я указал какие версии C и С++ и режим IntelliSense

Comment: А без отладки скомпилировать? А почему <iostream> не видит?

Comment: Просит перезагрузки компа, видимо шли обновления

Comment: @lk-production https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса